# Where can i get an Image and Photo Editing Software for free?

Tags: editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a good free image editor](https://superuser.com/questions/25451/looking-for-a-good-free-image-editor)

Hi!
Does anybody know there can i get an  Image and Photo Editing Software for free?

Comment: We are not the helpdesk.  We live in that room with the steel door in the basement.  No-one goes in and no-one comes out.  Most of us haven't spoken to a real person since 1712.  Voted to move.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/25451/looking-for-a-good-free-image-editor

Answer (score 10):

Try

- Paint.net http://www.getpaint.net/
- Gimp http://www.gimp.org/
- Picasa http://picasa.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

For those that prefer a Photoshop skin you could condider

[GimpShop](http://www.gimpshop.com/)

Personaly I would go with Gimp

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorites:

> **[PhotoFiltre](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/photofiltre.html)** is a complete image editing and effects package,
>   that will not only amaze you with
>   features but also the fact that it is
>   free (for personal use). It comes with
>   many features that rival some
>   commercial packages, as well as
>   additional add-on that can be
>   downloaded from the web site.
>   PhotoFiltre offers all the standard
>   editing features (selection, clone
>   brush, paint brush etc.) as well as a
>   large selection of image effects,
>   photo masks, image adjustments,
>   thumbnail browser and much more. The
>   program also supports batch processing
>   to apply filters, sizing, adjustments
>   and transformations to a large number
>   of images at once. PhotoFiltre comes
>   with modern, well designed interface
>   and is well suited for everything from
>   simple resizing to advanced photo
>   editing.

[image]

PhotoFiltre's got it all, low resource usage, extremely fast, ease of use and feature-packed.

*PhotoFiltre is freeware, a portable version is also available.*

Comment: +1 for the portable version - very good, very fast.

Answer (score 0):

[Pixlr](http://www.pixlr.com/editor) is a good, free, web-based image editor. It has most of the features that an average person would use Photoshop for.